# How does libc++'s std::is_literal_type work?

Tags: c++, c++17, std, libc++

This is the same situation for `std::is_literal_type` and `std::is_standard_layout`.

The implementation of `std::is_literal_type` in libc++ is

```
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_literal_type
#ifdef _LIBCPP_IS_LITERAL
    : public integral_constant<bool, _LIBCPP_IS_LITERAL(_Tp)>
#else
    : integral_constant<bool, is_scalar<typename remove_all_extents<_Tp>::type>::value ||
                              is_reference<typename remove_all_extents<_Tp>::type>::value>
#endif
    {};
```

There is no `_LIBCPP_IS_LITERAL`, so the code will be

```
template <typename T> struct is_literal_type : integral_constant<bool,
    is_scalar<typename remove_all_extents<T>::type>::value or
    is_reference<typename remove_all_extents<T>::type>::value> {};
```

I wrote a demo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct s {
    int a;
    char b;
    long c;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << is_scalar_v<typename remove_all_extents<s>::type> << endl;
    cout << is_reference_v<typename remove_all_extents<s>::type> << endl;
}
```

The result is `false` and `false`. But the result of `is_literal_type_v<s>` is `true`.

Could anyone explain how `std::is_literal_type` works?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but I find it helpful when modifying code to keep the original formatting until I'm sure it works; that makes it easier to ensure that there weren't inadvertent changes. Yours is correct, but it would be easier to see that if the format hadn't changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is_literal_type` is a "magic" C++ library thing. It *cannot* be implemented in C++ as the language currently stands (with static reflection, it should be possible, but that's C++23 at the soonest). It is implemented by using compiler-specific intrinsic tools, not by using C++ directly. `_LIBCPP_IS_LITERAL` is probably a macro defined by the compiler (hence it appearing undefined) which represents that particular compiler intrinsic.

As such, you really shouldn't look too closely at the implementation of this or many of the other type traits.

I imagine the version where `_LIBCPP_IS_LITERAL` is not defined is for compatibility with older versions of the compiler that did not expose the necessary intrinsic. So the library implementation does the best that it can without compiler support.

Comment: And just for completeness: the reason that the modified version gets the wrong answer is simply that it's (necessarily) incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the previous answer by @NicolBolas: It is probably wrong that `_LIBCPP_IS_LITERAL` is not set. Have a look at `__config.h`:

```
#if defined(_LIBCPP_COMPILER_CLANG)

[...]

#if __has_feature(is_literal)
#define _LIBCPP_IS_LITERAL(T) __is_literal(T)
#endif

[...]

#elif defined(_LIBCPP_COMPILER_GCC)

[...]

#if _GNUC_VER >= 407
[...]
#define _LIBCPP_IS_LITERAL(T) __is_literal_type(T)
[...]
#endif
```

Therefore the macro will be set if you are compiling with a recent enough Clang or GCC and in either case it will use a compiler intrinsic. `__is_literal` for Clang or `__is_literal_type` for GCC.

Both intrinsics are documented:

From https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html:

> __is_literal(type): Determines whether the given type is a literal type

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Traits.html:

> __is_literal_type (type)
>
> ```
> If type is a literal type ([basic.types]) the trait is true, else it is false. Requires: type shall be a complete type, (possibly cv-qualified) void, or an array of unknown bound.
> ```

---

You should not use these intrinsics directly though, because as you can see they are not portable. They are defined for the standard library developers.